# Softmax in last layer - error rises but when using sigmoid error decreases

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, softmax

I wrote a neural network from scratch in Python. It has 1 hidden layer which uses tanh activation function. I train it on Iris and MNIST datasets. When I use Sigmoid in the last layer results are very similar to Tensor Flow implementation. If I change Sigmoid to Softmax, learning error rises instead of falling. I got stuck at it.

[image: 1000 iterations on Iris with learning rate 0.01]

This is how I calculate learning error:

```
product = labels*pred
loss = -(np.sum((np.log(product[product!=0]))) / self.m[kind]) + reg
```

This is my back propagation loop:

```
// iterating from last layer to the first one
    for i in range(n_depth, 0, -1):
        if i == n_depth:
            # last layer
            dz = (self.cache_a[i] - self.labels[kind])
        else:
            # i = 1; s1 contain n1 neurons; (n1, m) = (n1, n2) x (n2, m) * (n1, m)
            dz = np.dot(self.weights[i+1].T, prev_dz)*self.d_tanh(self.cache_z[i])
        prev_dz = dz
        self.cache_dw[i] = np.dot(dz, self.cache_a[i-1].T) / self.m[kind]
        self.cache_db[i] = np.sum(dz, axis=1, keepdims=True) / self.m[kind]
        # no regularization
        if(self.regularization):
            reg = (self.reg_lambda * self.weights[i]) / self.m[kind]
        else:
            reg = 0;
        self.weights[i] = self.weights[i] - self.alpha * (self.cache_dw[i] + reg)
        self.bias[i] = self.bias[i] - self.alpha * self.cache_db[i]
    #end for
```

Softmax:

```
def softmax(self, z):
    """softmax - multi-class, single-label
    """
    t = np.exp(z - np.max(z))
    return t / np.sum(t)
#end
```

If I remove `- np.max(z)` from softmax the error increases faster.

Errors with `- np.max(z)`:

```
Last train error:  6.20518290954117
Last cv error:  5.505586272828439
```

Errors and learning curve without `- np.max(z)`:

```
Last train error:  13.856890930850874
Last cv error:  15.972665792136079
```

[image: learning curve without <code>- np.max(z)</code>]

Forward propagation loop:

```
    for i in range(1, len(self.network_map)+1):
        # cache_z.shape = (n-next + 1, 1)
        # b's shape is (i+1,1) and it's added to the new matrix before activation fn is applied
        # it is broadcasted to all results along m axis
        layer_z = np.dot(weights[i], self.cache_a[i-1]) + bias[i]
        # Save layerZ in cache for back prop
        self.cache_z.append(layer_z)
        if i == len(self.network_map):
            # Last is softmax/sigmoid
            layer_a = self.softmax(layer_z)
            #layer_a = self.sigmoid(layer_z)
        else:
            # Non-last are tanh
            layer_a = self.tanh(layer_z)
        np.nan_to_num(layer_a, False)
        self.cache_a.append(layer_a)
    #end for
```

Most likely the error is somewhere in back prop. but I am not sure. Can you spot it or give me some tips?

Here is the whole class: https://github.com/al1357/ml/blob/master/neural_network.py

Comment: Why are you subtracting max(z) inside exp() for your soft max?

Comment: @kbrose it is normalizing softmax inputs to prevent NaNs in Python if they are large. I took the idea from [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/#computing-softmax-and-numerical-stability).

Comment: What happens if you don’t do that?

Comment: @kbrose the error increases at faster rate - I included a graph in my question.

Comment: Sorry for taking shots in the dark, without all the code it's hard to test. What if you add a small constant in your division? E.g. `return t / (np.sum(t) + 1e-5)`

Comment: @kbrose no worries. When I add this number error curve and values stay roughly the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because the accepted answer illustrates that this arose due to a coding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the softmax function. `t / np.sum(t)` sums all numbers in `n x m` array while I only need the sum along axis 0. After correcting to `np.sum(t, axis=0)` it works and the error decreases.